# Encrypted Decimal Values getting rounded off automatically on insertion

Tags: sql-server, mybatis

I have to store some decimal values in backend. I use symmetric to encrypt the data as:

```
encryptbykey(key_guid(#{keyName}), convert(nvarchar(1024), #{variable})),
```

And the following to decrypt the data as:

```
convert(nvarchar(1024), decryptbykey(variable2))
```

When I use same commands on SQL Server manually, everything is encrypted correctly. But in case of this happening via application, they are rounded off after 5 digits. I checked via debugged, the decimals are coming fine till the DAO layer and something is happening on insertion.

Comment: I think the datatype you are using in the application is not decimal. may be float. please check

Comment: Also why convert to `nvarchar` why not encrypt the bytes themselves by casting to `varbinary`?

Comment: used bigDecimal, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exaclty sure, but used BigDeciaml and it worked.

PS: I tried to remove the encryption and use decimal, everything was working fine. Looks like issue in encrypting. Have used the above hack to make it work for now.